# Core Data (Magical Record) pausing main thread when fetching

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, magicalrecord

I have a method that looks like this:

```
+ (Cat *)fetchCatWithId:(NSString *)catId {
    NSManagedObjectContext* context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
    NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id ==[c] %@", catId];
    Cat* cat = [Cat MR_findFirstWithPredicate:predicate inContext:context];
    return cat;
}
```

The Xcode Time Profiler is showing a pretty big hit on the line

```
Cat* cat = [Cat MR_findFirstWithPredicate:predicate inContext:context];
```

And indeed, the UI in my app freezes briefly when this happens. So apparently I need to do this fetch on a background thread. So I have three questions:

1. Is there a way to perform the fetch faster?
2. If not, how do I do the fetch on a background thread?
3. This method returns a Cat object. Obviously there are other parts of the app that are requesting the Cat. So do I now need to add a completion handler to this method and refactor everything to do things only on completion of performing the fetch? This doesn't seem right.

Comment: `+ (id) MR_findFirstWithPredicate:(NSPredicate *)searchTerm inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;` use `performBlockAndWait` inside. so, your code `wait`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
+ (Cat *)fetchCatWithId:(NSString *)catId {
   Cat *cat = [Cat MR_findFirstByAttribute: @"id" withValue: catID];
   return cat;
}
```

Comment: ... which will effectively be the same as the OPs approach. So, it's neither faster nor does it execute on a different thread or dispatch queue.

Comment: Not necessarily, 'MR_findFirstByAttribute' doesn't use a predicate, which is what I am guessing is where the delay from the OP originates from. But I could be mistaken.

Comment: It will do something like this:   `NSFetchRequest *request = [self MR_createFetchRequestInContext:context];`
    `[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K = %@", property, value]];`

Comment: So maybe the [c] in the predicate of the OP is slowing it down?

Comment: I don't think that case insensitive is that much slower compared to case sensitive (default). In order to improve performance, we need to start with an appropriate "Core Data stack" having a "root managed object context" which is associated to the persistent store, running on a private queue. The root context has child context "main managed object context" associated to main thread.

Comment: CouchDeveloper is right, MR_findFirstByAttribute will eventually create a predicate anyway.

Comment: So the answer to question 1 is probably NO. Still wondering about questions 2 and 3...

Comment: You can find the answer to 2 in the Core Data docs from Apple.